# Three js add video to plane geometry

Tags: video, three.js, geometry, plane

I'm trying to display a video into a plane geometry with three js, but all i get is a black rectangle.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
texture.needsUpdate;
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
texture.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

var imageObject = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }),);

scene.add( imageObject );
```

Added:

```
video.src = "src to video";
video.load();
video.play();
```

And works!

Comment: When and how do you start playing [video](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)?

Comment: Nowhere, i have set 'autoplay' in the tag video in the html. I think that's the problem

Comment: You could provide more information and code then.

Comment: Html video tag: `<video id="video" autoplay loop webkit-playsinline style="display:none"></video>` i have added the functions found in the page you linked and now works. Thanks!

Comment: It may be like that because you haven't put [`<source>`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/da2936540a48774b043a1e617bddbdce5102e417/examples/webgl_materials_video.html#L53) tag.

Comment: Yes, i have edited the post with the missing code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding video as Texture in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884013/adding-video-as-texture-in-three-js)

Comment: If you've solved this , you should add your answer and accept your answer. This helps people find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, add this code:

```
video.src = "src to video";
video.load();
video.play();
```