# Is it possible to create this effect with a video vs webcam?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video

I recently saw [this example of three.js videotexture](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/webcam-audio-visualizer/index2.html) and I am trying to learn where to begin to duplicate this concept.

In the example, they are using the webcam as the video source and I can seem to figure out how to get it to function with a normal video as the src.

I've believe the source that I need to adjust is here, but I am having no luck.  [Full code](https://github.com/r21nomi/webcam-audio-visualizer)

HTML

```
<video id="video" class="hidden"></video>
```

JS

```
T = () => {
        (l = document.getElementById("video")).autoplay = !0;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: !0,
            audio: !1
        }).then(t => {
            l.srcObject = t, l.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => 
   {
                p = l.videoWidth, f = l.videoHeight, R()
            })
        }).catch(t => {
            console.log(t), I()
        })
    },
```

I can get the video to show up but it won't include the videotexture from the threejs.

I'm just looking for a point in the right direction to get this figured out!

thank you!
xx

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884013/adding-video-as-texture-in-three-js/37892861 ?

Comment: @TheJim01 unfortunately not .. :(

Comment: I don't mean this as "did you Google it?" but there are lots of examples of using video as a texture. Could you update your question with a few of the links you've examined, and a short comment each on why the example didn't meet your needs?

Comment: @TheJim01 It's this particular effect in this example that is very unique to me.  In the [article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/09/06/how-to-create-a-webcam-audio-visualizer-with-three-js/) the writer mentions that he loads the webcam as the src of the video.  I thought it would be easy to just have it read the actual src of the video, but i am having no luck.

Comment: @TheJim01 to make matters worse, the code that the writer has in the article is different from the source provided!  so i know google will help in a broad sense, I was just hoping for a push in the right direction in this particular case!

Comment: I have one more stupid question... Does the video play as a normal `video` element? Like just as an element in the HTML, rather than as the source for the texture?

Comment: Kind of - the video element (the webcam) is hidden.  it is also drawn into a canvas element @TheJim01

Comment: I feel like I'm so close.  It using getUserMedia and assigning that to the src of the video.  I can't seem to make it just a link to the src!  It seems to be about src vs. srcobject, and if use srcobject then I get a console error that this isn't a mediasteam, its a mediasource!  ahhh!!

Comment: Since these comments are getting a little long, could you please head over to chat.stackoverflow.com and join the "video in three.js" room?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation to chat there.  thanks for your help anyway, I'll work through it!